# Creating multiple objects inside loop

Tags: ruby, loops, object, iteration

The below code overwrites @journey_lines 10 times leaving only the last journey saved as an array. I want to create a new array object for each journey (1 to 10).

```
# Save text file to string
data = File.read("workdata.txt")

# Split string into blocks of text relevant to each journey
journeys = data.split(/\n\s\n/)

# Store the amount of journeys as a variable called journeys_size
journeys_size = journeys.length

# Split each journey into lines and save to an array called "journey_lines"
journeys[1..10].each { |i| @journey_lines = i.split(/\n/) }

# Inspect journey_lines 
p @journey_lines
```

Is there a way of inserting a variable into the iteration value? Something like...

```
journeys[1..#journeys.size].each { |i| @journey_lines[1..#journeys_size] = i.split(/\n/) }
```

Or a better way of doing this all together. I've been trying to do this for a while. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `map` method instead

```
@journey_lines = journey.map {|item| item.split(/\n/) }
```

Comment: You can use `lines` in place of `split(/\n/)` so long as the global variable `$/` equals its default value,`\n`.